# Compiling one .exe file from 2 projects

Tags: c#, visual-studio, exe

I have a c# solution that holds 2 projects (1 for the codes of data handling and 1 for the winform UI) the desktop project also holds an access file in its bin folder.

My question is, how do I create an .exe file of the solution that I can send out and it will work?

Comment: Have you made your "data handling" project a class library? (Can be done in the project properties, if not).

Comment: I don't think you can do it. Each project in VS would be compiled into a dll or and exe individually. Why would you want to create a single exe from 2 projects. You can create an exe and a dll and send it out, it should still work, till the time you are shipping all the necessary supporting dlls and other resources required by the application.

Comment: Check [this](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17630) out

Answer (score 1):

From your requirement, what I understand is you need to embed the dll in the exe. From VS `Project(Your exe project) Properties -> Resources -> Add Resource -> Add Existing File`

Answer (score 0):

If UI project refers to "data project", on compilation of UI project in its Debug or Release (based on compilation configuration choice) folder you will find all binaries you need to run UI.

Will this work simply copy/paste on client machine noone can say other then you, as it strongly depends on *how* your program works.